# Why does ' dir(1) is dir(True) ' return False

Tags: python

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) quieston's answer

> *is will return True if two variables point to the same object, == if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.*

Aren't `dir(1)` and `dir(True)` point to the same object? Both of them prints a list of the same methods. Am I missing something about *object* here?

```
>>> dir(1) == dir(True)
True
>>> dir(1) is dir(True)
False
>>>
```

Comment: You answered yourself.

Comment: They point to two distinct objects, which happen to have the same content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `True` is not `1`:

```
>>> True is not 1
True
```

Second, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) says

> `dir([object])`
>
> [...] With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.
>
> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects that implement a custom `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()` function to customize the way `dir()` reports their attributes.
>
> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its best to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a custom `__getattr__()`.
>
> The resulting list is sorted alphabetically. [...]

---

Now, `int` and `bool` both have the `__dir__` slot filled from `object.__dir__`:

```
>>> int.__dir__
<method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>
>>> bool.__dir__
<method '__dir__' of 'object' objects>
```

---

And the documentation for [`object.__dir__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__) adds this one extra bit of information:

> **`object.__dir__(self)`**
>
> Called when `dir()` is called on the object. A sequence must be returned. `dir()` converts the returned sequence to a list and sorts it.

As the documentation says, `dir` constructs a *new* list for *each invocation* and then *sorts* it. (We could also look into the code for [`_dir_object`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fa2b18ad4ea6479f43fd31e3a42baeac8784289c/Objects/object.c#L1300) which calls [`PySequence_List`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fa2b18ad4ea6479f43fd31e3a42baeac8784289c/Objects/object.c#L1319) on the return value of `__dir__`; `PySequence_List` takes a sequence as an argument, and returns a *new* list with the same elements as the original sequence; this newly created list is then [sorted](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fa2b18ad4ea6479f43fd31e3a42baeac8784289c/Objects/object.c#L1323) and [returned](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fa2b18ad4ea6479f43fd31e3a42baeac8784289c/Objects/object.c#L1327))

```
>>> a = 1
>>> dir(a) is dir(a)
False
```

---

Third, `True` is an instance of type `bool`, which is a subclass of `int`.

```
 >>> isinstance(True, bool)
 True
 >>> isinstance(1, int)
 True
 >>> issubclass(bool, int)
 True
 >>> isinstance(True, int)
 True
```

Additionally, `bool` does not add any methods that are not already present in `int`. And because the resulting list is sorted alphabetically,

```
>>> dir(1) == dir(True)
True
```

Comment: *"As the documentation says"* - Where does it?

Comment: @StefanPochmann the documentation says that `dir()` gathers the data from the object's `__dict__` attribute, and then sorts it alphabetically. However I need to add a clarification that there is `__dir__` there

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Third part is helped me for understand this.

Comment: If `(1).__dir__()` always returns the same list and the "conversion" is like `if not isinstance(x, list): x = list(x)` and the sorting is like `x.sort()`, then `dir` would always return the same list, not a new one.

Comment: Ha, I don't really like reading the C code, I'll just trust what you say there. That's the source code, though, not the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime thet you execute `dir` the new object is created.

```
>>> dir(True) is dir(True)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir` creates a new object for the `int` that it's returning each time.

Basically you got confused between `1 is True` and `dir(1) is dir(True)` and `dir(1) == dir(True)`.